# Run function from structure variable

Tags: c

I try to run a function with a structure, because I work with a module who send callback so I want to execute the fuction to anwser to the callback.

```
typedef void (*bgs2_e_rx_callback)(unsigned char reason, unsigned short int n, char * data);
void bgs_callbacktest(char* data);

/*void test(int* ptest);
void test_tab(char* data,char* ptaille);
char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2);
static void parse_numeric_rsp(char nb_values, char * data, unsigned long data_len,unsigned long * result);*/

struct teststruct{
    short int i  ;
    bgs2_e_rx_callback callback;
    void* param;
};

struct teststruct leteststruct ;

 int main(){
    printf("test for function in structure\n");
    char txt[]="i'm a text";
    leteststruct.param = txt;
    leteststruct.callback = &bgs_callbacktest;

 }


 void bgs_callbacktest(char* data){
     printf("your text: %s\n",leteststruct.param);

 }
```

Compilation works good, but I don't see the message of the callback function.

Comment: You never call the callback.

Comment: I thought that assigning the function triggers its execution

Comment: `bgs_callbacktest` and `bgs2_e_rx_callback` have different function prototypes. I would expect a warning from the compiler about assignment from incompatible pointer type.

Comment: @Hicham: Of course not. It's just pointer assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call it! Edit your main like this:

```c
int main(){
    printf("test for function in structure\n");
    char txt[]="i'm a text";
    leteststruct.param = txt;
    leteststruct.callback = bgs_callbacktest;

    // Change the dummy parameters below with yours
    leteststruct.callback(0x7f, 512, txt);
 }
```

Then you will have it.

Comment: thank you for your anwser, but when it tell me " main.c|29|error: too few arguments to function 'leteststruct.callback "

Comment: i change the code to delete the input " char* data" but it still not working !

Comment: Uh, man forgot to pass your parameters :) I will update the code with dummy parameters, then you modify them for your needs.

Comment: Glad you achieved it. You can mark this answer as solution if it worked for you. Good luck.